# Effective placement of lock_guard - from item 16 from Effective Modern C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic

In item 16: "Make const member functions thread safe" there is a code as follows:

```
class Widget {
public:    
  int magicValue() const
  {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(m);  // lock m    
    if (cacheValid) return cachedValue;
    else {
      auto val1 = expensiveComputation1();
      auto val2 = expensiveComputation2();
      cachedValue = val1 + val2;
      cacheValid = true;
      return cachedValue;
    }
  }                                        // unlock m    
private:
  mutable std::mutex m;
  mutable int cachedValue;                 // no longer atomic
  mutable bool cacheValid{ false };        // no longer atomic
};
```

I wonder why std::lock_guard should be executed always on each magicValue() call, wouldnt following work as expected?:

```
class Widget {
public:

  int magicValue() const
  {

    if (cacheValid) return cachedValue;
    else {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(m);  // lock m
      if (cacheValid) return cachedValue;          
      auto val1 = expensiveComputation1();
      auto val2 = expensiveComputation2();
      cachedValue = val1 + val2;
      cacheValid = true;
      return cachedValue;
    }
  }                                        // unlock m

private:
  mutable std::atomic<bool>  cacheValid{false};
  mutable std::mutex m;
  mutable int cachedValue;                 // no longer atomic
};
```

This way fewer mutex locks would be required, making code more efficient. I assume here that atomica are always faster than mutexes.

[edit]

For completness I measured efficiency of both apraches, and the second looks like is only 6% faster.: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e8ce9c3cfd3a4019

Comment: Because reading cacheValid may not be atomic?

Comment: @NeilButterworth: welcome back.

Comment: You understand, that your computation can be run more than once with the second version

Comment: @steve actually I dont, can you write and answer why? I thought making cacheValid a std::atomic<bool> would suffice, also there is a lock_guard which I suppose should prevent double computation.

Comment: you check for cacheValid, which is false, the code will switch to the else case, The thread gets interrupted at that point. The next thread checks cacheValid which is still false, goes to the else case.......

Comment: ok, `.....goes to the else case.` and gets locked by std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(m); - it was previously entered by some other thread which started computation.

Comment: @NeilButterworth How is that possible? `cacheValid` is an atomic variable. All reads and writes on it must be atomic. Even with the most relaxed memory load/write, the operation is still atomic.

Comment: @steve The computation cannot be run more than once. Although it is possible that the mutex protected area is accessed by multiple threads, the second check of the `atomic` flag prevents multiple computations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second code snippet shows a perfectly valid implementation of the *Double Checked Locking Pattern* (DCLP) and is (probably) more efficient that Meyers' solution since it avoids locking the `mutex` unnecessarily after `cachedValue` is set.

It is guaranteed that the expensive computations are not performed more than once.

Also, it is important that the `cacheValid` flag is `atomic` because it creates a *happens-before* relationship between writing-to and reading-from `cachedValue`.
In other words, it synchronizes `cachedValue` (which is accessed outside of the `mutex`) with other threads calling `magicValue()`.
Had `cacheValid` been a regular 'bool', you would have had a data race on both `cacheValid` and `cachedValue` (causing undefined behavior per the C++11 standard).

Using default sequential consistent memory ordering on the `cacheValid` memory operations is fine, since it implies acquire/release semantics.
In theory, you could optimize by using weaker memory orderings on the `atomic` loads and store:

```
int Widget::magicValue() const
{

  if (cacheValid.load(std::memory_order_acquire)) return cachedValue;
  else {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(m);  // lock m
    if (cacheValid.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)) return cachedValue;
    auto val1 = expensiveComputation1();
    auto val2 = expensiveComputation2();
    cachedValue = val1 + val2;
    cacheValid.store(true, std::memory_order_release);
    return cachedValue;
  }
}
```

Note that this is only a minor optimization since reading an `atomic` is a regular load on many platforms (making it as efficient as reading from a non-atomic).

As pointed out by Nir Friedman, this only works one way; you cannot invalidate `cacheValid` and restart calculations. But that was not part of Meyers' example.

Answer (score 2):

I actually think that your snippet is correct in isolation, but it relies on an assumption that is usually not true in a real world example: it assumes that the `cacheValid` goes from false to true, but can never make the reverse progression, that is become invalidated.

In the old code, the `mutex` protects *all* reads *and* writes on `cachedValue`. In your new code, there's actually a read access of `cachedValue` outside the mutex. That means that it is possible for one thread to read this value, while another thread is writing it. The catch is that the reading outside the mutex will only occur if `cacheValid` is true. But if `cacheValid` is true, no writing will occur; `cacheValid`  can only become true *after* all writing is complete (note that this is enforced, because the assignment operator on `cacheValid` will use the strictest memory ordering guarantee, so it cannot be reordered with the earlier instructions in the block).

But suppose some other piece of code is written, that can invalidate the cache: `Widget::invalidateCache()`. This piece of code does nothing but set `cacheValid` to false again. In the old code, if you called `invalidateCache` and `magicValue` repeatedly from different threads, the latter function might recalculate the value or not at any given point. But even if your complex calculations are returning different values each time they are called (because they use global state, say), you will always get either the old or new value, and nothing else. But now consider the following execution order in your code:

1. Thread 1 calls `magicValue`, and checks the value of `cacheValid`. It's true. It gets interrupted before it can continue.
2. Thread 2 calls `invalidateCache`, and then immediately calls `magicValue`. `magicValue` sees that the cache is invalid, acquires the mutex, and starts computing, and *begins* writing to `cacheValid`.
3. Thread 1 interrupts, reading a partially written `cacheValid`.

I actually don't think this example works on most modern computers, because `int` will typically be 32 bits, and typically 32 bit writes and reads will be atomic. So it's not really possible to intersperse or "tear" the value of `cachedValue`. But on different architectures, or if you use a type other than integer (anything over 64 bits, for example), writing or reading is not guaranteed to be atomic. So you can get, as a return for `magicValue`, something which is neither the old value nor the new value but some weird bitwise hybrid that is not even a valid object.

So, good on you for finding this. I guess that in trying to boil down the example for simplicity, the author forgot that it was no longer necessary to be strict about putting the mutex on the outside.

Comment: you are correct that on most platforms there are no torn reads or writes possible on an integer.
But another problem with setting the flag invalid is that cachedValue (a non-atomic) may now be concurrently read from and written to. That is a data race which has undefined behavior